# My json request will not fire a beforeSend request.. Can't seem to figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Notes**

1. This is jQuery 1.4.4
2. This is *not* a jsonp request. Just vanilla json within my domain.

**My Request**

```
$autocomplete_xhr = $.ajax({
  url: '/customers/filter.json',
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: { name: request.term },
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
   console.log('Inside beforeSend');
   console.log(xhr);
  },
```

When I send the AJAX request out, `console.log` will not fire off.

What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Can you start by upgrading to the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: Oh my gosh, now I'm embarressed. This is a huge application with tons of things going on. It would set back development more than this small issue is worth.

Comment: there is no harm if you update the jQuery, in fact you will see that your application will run faster

Comment: What if there's hidden deprecation issues with the upgrade? :D I'm worried things will start breaking all over the place, and I won't find out for weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clearly said in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)**

> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR
>   (in **jQuery 1.4.x**, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use
>   this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings maps are
>   passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the
>   beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.

Comment: Reading this it seems that beforeSend works in 1.4.x. Am I wrong? Would it not work in this version? Sorry for the dumb questions.

Comment: `beforeSend` will work, but in 1.4.x it will give you access to an `XMLHTTPREQUEST` object *not* `jqXHR`

Comment: Granted. But console.log still doesn't fire as it never actually goes inside the beforeSend statement. Even if I change it to an `XMLHTTPRequest`. :D

Comment: It works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AGfrc/ - ignoring the error due to the URL not existing.

Comment: Hmm.. must be something else then. Thanks Rory and diEcho